# Clenshaw-type recurrence for derivative of Chebyshev series

Tags: numerical-analysis, stability, chebyshev

The naive summation of a Chebyshev series
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{c_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_{k}T_{k}(x)
\end{align*}
which employs the three-term recurrence for evaluation of the Chebyshev polynomials is known to be numerically unstable near $x=\pm 1$. For this reason, Clenshaw presented an algorithm which avoids this instability; see [Clenshaw's original work](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1955-09-051/S0025-5718-1955-0071856-0/S0025-5718-1955-0071856-0.pdf) and an exposition in Algorithm 3.1 of [Numerical Methods for Special Functions](https://www.siam.org/books/ot99/OT99SampleChapter.pdf).

Is there literature which presents a numerically stable method for evaluating the derivative of a Chebyshev series, perhaps using an analogy to the Clenshaw recurrence presented above? Or is the naive method stable?

Comment: A useful alternative to the answer you got is to derive the Chebyshev coefficients of the derivative from the coefficients of the original function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just take Clenshaw's recurrence
$$ u_k(x) = 2xu_{k+1}(x)-u_{k+2}(x)+\color{red}{a_k},\\
f(x) = x u_1(x)-u_2(x)+\color{red}{a_0} $$
and differentiate it directly:
$$ u_k'(x) = 2xu_{k+1}'(x)-u_{k+2}'(x) + \color{blue}{2u_{k+1}(x)},\\
f'(x) = x u_1'(x)-u_2'(x) + \color{blue}{u_1(x)}. $$
Note that now the derivatives of partial sums, $u_k'(x)$ satisfy *exactly* the same recurrence, except that the coefficients $a_k$ are replaced by $2u_{k+1}(x)$. This means that the series for the derivative can be written as the Chebyshev series
$$ f'(x) = \tfrac12 u_1(x) + \sum_{k\geq1} 2u_{k+1}(x)T_k(x). $$

Since Clenshaw's recurrence evaluates Chebyshev series accurately, it will evaluate the Chebyshev series with coefficients $2u_{k+1}(x)$ accurately too, and it doesn't need to be analyzed separately. A very similar thing happens when differentiating polynomials using Horner's rule.

Comment: This is effectively a manual application of automatic differentiation on the loop for Clenshaw's recurrence. It should be noted that this method is easily extensible if one wants second, third, ... $n$-th order derivatives.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, but *manual application of automatic differentiation* is just plain old "differentiation" ;-)

Comment: This answer is so good; I keep coming back to it for insights. As with most things, everything is trivial after you know it, but how many people know this? It definitely deserves to be more widely known.